# ContentChildren and html tag (Angular2)

Tags: angular, angular2-template

How can I get `<div>` with `ContentChildren`?

By id I know I can use #.

```
    <my-component>
      <div #id>
         ...

//inside my-component    
ContentChildren('id') ....
```

But how can I get `div` or `span` or `button` without defining id attribute?

**Edited** (I want to do that):

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div>
        <my-component>
              <div>Hey from div.</div>
        </my-component>
    </div>
  `
})
export class AppComponent {
}

@Component({
  selector: 'my-component',
  template: `
    <div class="example-wrapper">
        <div *ngIf="template" [ngTemplateOutlet]="template"></div>
    </div>
  `
})
export class MyComponent {
    @ContentChildren('.div') template: ItemTemplateDirective;

    ngOnInit(): void
    {
      console.log(this.template);
    }
}
```

Comment: share your code so that we will know what exactly you want to do

Comment: as an alternative you can use any directive on an element and then use `@ContentChildren(DirectiveClass)`

Comment: @AngularInDepth.com I added detailed source code.

Comment: it's not possible, I pointed to the other possible solution using directives